# install.packages("devtools") on R 3.0.2 fails in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu

I am trying to install the R 3.0.2 `devtools` package on Ubuntu 14.04 as follows:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

I get the following results:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/jim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available
also installing the dependency ‘rversions’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rversions_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4624 bytes
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 4624 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_1.8.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 141487 bytes (138 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 138 Kb

ERROR: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available for package ‘rversions’
* removing ‘/home/jim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rversions’
ERROR: dependency ‘rversions’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/jim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/devtools’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpmDzsRJ/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘rversions’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status
```

It appears there is a dependency on a package named `xml2`.  Does anyone know where I can find this package and how I can install it.

I have already installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: Install R 3.2.0 from [this Ubuntu repo on every CRAN mirror](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu); everything will fall into place.

Comment: sudo apt-get update
...
and then
sudo apt-get install r-base
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  r-base
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/9,568 B of archives.
After this operation, 73.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package r-base.
(Reading database ... 201581 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../r-base_3.0.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking r-base (3.0.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up r-base (3.0.2-1ubuntu1) ...
jim@Ubuntu14:~$

3.0.2 is still being installed

Comment: Did you add an entry to /etc/apt/sources.list as suggested in the link posted by @DirkEddelbuettel?

Answer (score 24):

If R is installed in Ubuntu using the software center, the stable version at the time of the Ubuntu build is built is included. Hence R 3.0.2 is installed.

Adding the following to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

resulted in the current version (R 3.2.0) being loaded.

I had to install the following OpenSSL library

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

and then I was able to start R and successfully install 'devtools'

Many thanks to Dirk and Pascal for their advice.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! this worked for me. please edit the location of sources.list file to  /etc/apt/sources.list :)

Comment: Here are the available Ubuntu mirrors: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ and here the list of servers: https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html. In my case this line made the trick: deb http://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu vivid/

Answer (score 15):

Another solution (on version R 3.2.2) is to installing lxml:

> $ apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev

which successfully removed the R error:

> Error: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’

appearing in R when running

> install.packages("devtools")

Comment: The `libxml2-dev` dependency also fixes potential installation issues with `roxygen2` on Debian-based Linuxes.