# cannot install r packages on IR kernel (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

My company has a Jupyter Notebook cloud that can let me run R on it; however, I cannot install packages such as 'tm' or 'rpart'on it. Can anyone help me to solve it? Thank you very much!

The code and warning messages are shown as following:

```
install.packages("tm", lib = '/home/jiafei', repos= 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')

Warning message in install.packages("tm", lib = "/home/jiafei", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
“installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("tm", lib = "/home/jiafei", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
“installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status”
```

Comment: Consider installing `xml2` prior to installing `tm`.

Comment: Hi Roman, I just tried to install `xm12` but the console told me that `Warning message:
“package ‘xm12’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)”`

Comment: that's a lowercase L, you used a one

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! however, I'm still not able to install `xml2` :( probably since I'm not in the U.S.?

Comment: Please incorporate errors from your attempts of installing `xml2` into your question.

Comment: `Warning message in install.packages("xml2", lib = "/home/jiafei", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org"):
“installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status”` Sorry that I forgot to post the error message.

Comment: Any other messages? Are you perhaps behind a firewall?

Comment: Nope, now I have successfully installed `rpart` and `ggplot2` but still can't install `xml2`

Comment: Perhaps you need OpenSSL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794035/install-packagesdevtools-on-r-3-0-2-fails-in-ubuntu-14-04